# PowerShell Add_Click in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, winforms, foreach

What I am trying to accomplish is to create buttons that launch exe files in a certain directory when clicked, but when I try using a foreach loop to create a few buttons, all of the buttons just launch the file the last button is supposed to launch.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Main Window'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400)

$flp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$flp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$flp.Height = $form.Height
$flp.Width = $form.Width
$form.Controls.Add($flp)

$files = Get-ChildItem "$home\Downloads" -Include *.exe -Name

foreach ($file in $files){
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $flp.Controls.Add($button)
    $button.Width = 100
    $button.Height = 50
    $button.Text = $file
    $button.Add_Click{
        Start-Process -FilePath "$home\Downloads\$file"
    }
}

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Whatever I'm doing is probably pretty stupid, so I was just looking for any alternatives or solutions to this other than to just hard code everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you need to use [`.GetNewClosure()` ScriptBlock method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) so that each script block (button click event) holds the current value of the `$file` variable at the moment of enumeration.

Example of what this means:

```
$blocks = foreach($i in 0..5) {
    { "hello $i" }
}
& $blocks[0] # => hello 5
& $blocks[1] # => hello 5

$blocks = foreach($i in 0..5) {
    { "hello $i" }.GetNewClosure()
}
& $blocks[0] # => hello 0
& $blocks[1] # => hello 1
```

In that sense, and assuming this is the issue, the following should work:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $button        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Width  = 100
    $button.Height = 50
    $button.Text   = $file
    $thisEvent     = {
        Start-Process -FilePath "$home\Downloads\$file"
    }.GetNewClosure()
    $button.Add_Click($thisEvent)
    $flp.Controls.Add($button)
}
```

---

A nice alternative to having a need to use `.GetNewClosure()` can be seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196325/15339544). The [`.Tag` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-tag) of the [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#properties) can be used to store the information of the file's path which then can be used on the button's `.Click` event:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $button        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Width  = 100
    $button.Height = 50
    $button.Text   = $file
    # Store the file's path in the Tag's property of this Button
    $button.Tag    = "$home\Downloads\$file"
    $button.Add_Click({
        Start-Process -FilePath $this.Tag
    })
    $flp.Controls.Add($button)
}
```