# Button doesn't register the right callback

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script with a GUI where I a button per file in a directory.

I have this loop to create the button:

```
$i = 100
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $savePath -recurse -include *.json) {
    $filename = Split-Path $file.FullName -leaf
    $saveName = $filename -split "\."
    $btn                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $saveName1 = $saveName[1]
    $btn.text              = "Load save $saveName1"
    $btn.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$i)
    $btn.width             = 200
    $btn.height            = 30
    $btn.Add_Click({
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($filename.clone() , $saveName1.clone())
        copy_and_print (New-Object String $filename.clone()) (New-Object String $saveName1.clone())
    })
    $LocalPrinterForm.controls.Add($btn)
    $i = $i + 40
}
```

But when I click on a button the values of `$filename` and `$saveName1` are always the one corresponding to the last file (I've added `.clone()` to try to avoid references issues but it doesn't fix my issue).

For example if I have those files: `a.json` and `b.json` then the `MessageBox` will always print `b.json` independently of which button I click.

How do I make sure that the right callback get registered for each button?

Comment: Take a look at this, I believe you have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/70919366/15339544

Comment: [1] Why don't you use the properties `.Name` and `.BaseName` instead of trying to split on the dot (a file could have several dots in its name..) [2] A button control also has a `.Name` and a [.Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-tag) property you could use to store the filename in, so each button always 'knows' what file it is dealing with.

Comment: Regarding the values always being the ones for the last file, should be explained on the linked answer, on the other hand instead of having multiple buttons per file why not look into different classes in WinForms to hold the file list? I.e DataGridView or ListBox

Comment: Theo's answer is an elegant alternative approach that avoids the original problem, which is indeed the same as in the post that @SantiagoSquarzon linked to: a script block that references outside variables resolves their values _when called_ - unless outside variables are locked in at block creation time via `.GetNewClosure()`

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, you can utilize the button control's `.Tag` property to store information for that particular button to use:

```
$i = 100
# using -Filter is MUCH faster than -Include
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $savePath -Recurse -Filter '*.json' -File)) {
    $btn          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn.text     = "Load save $($file.Extension)"
    $btn.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$i)
    $btn.width    = 200
    $btn.height   = 30
    # save the needed properties as object in the Tags property of the button control
    $btn.Tag      = $file | Select-Object FullName, Name, Extension
    $btn.Add_Click({
        # inside the click handler, you can refer to the button object 
        # itself with automatic variable $this
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($this.Tag.Name, $this.Tag.Extension)
        copy_and_print $this.Tag.Name $this.Tag.Extension
    })
    $LocalPrinterForm.controls.Add($btn)
    $i += 40  # next y position
}
```

We do not know what your `copy_and_print` function does, but perhaps the first parameter should be the file's FullName. In that case change to

```
copy_and_print $this.Tag.FullName $this.Tag.Extension
```